# How to Open file without download using phonegap

Tags: android, ios

I am working in cross platform using phonegap. When i tried Download Phonegap API in IOS, file is getting downloaded in phone rather in SD Card So its not safe to save it phone,so Please Suggest me solution So that it support both Android and ios to open file to view without downloading.....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

For **Android**:

You can use `FileOpener` plugin to do the same. This plugin will help you to open all the files store in your asset folder in android and resource folder in iOS. As well as you can open global image as well.

Have a look on this github page you will able to find the [plugin](https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener).

You no need to download any content.

And **For iOS** you can use only:

```
function openFile(url) {
window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: in the plugin they mentioned as it supports  and tested in android ... i want to open file both in android and ios...

Answer (score 0):

You can get file link from server  and open in InAppBrowser

```
var ref = window.open(your_url, 'random_string', 'location=no');

ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {

});
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
     console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);

});
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {

});
```

Comment: Thank you For the solution ..its working in both android and Ios but i am not able to open pdf files....  so please suggest solution for it...

Comment: its also work, i have opened pdf also in my app. I think its take time. Check small size pdf like one page...

Comment: Hi,it works fine in ios and in android its not suppoting.....so i tried to open with g0ogle doc by prefixing this https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url= ,then i was able to open pdf file...............but with prefix of that if i give any text,image or other thing its giving html file of it.............so how can i open pdf and all other kinds of file.......

Comment: tell InAppBrowser working in android or not read this one 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849338/phonegap-android-inappbrowser-not-working

Comment: and i tried by using _system also instead of _blank the files are getting downloaded and then it's opening files........i dont want files to get downloaded, just to open files to view it...........

Comment: Its all problem in android then try to install InAppBrowser.

Comment: how i can add docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url= as a prefix to the url if the file is only pdf ..............can youu suggest me solution for it please........

Comment: its not working ...........if i add url in the var ref = window.open('url', '_blank', 'location=yes'); its refering to the path of assets/www/url and it display webpage not available.

Comment: no other pages also not able to display.....if i add any kind of url like url containing image or text in var ref = window.open('url', '_blank', 'location=yes')its not working........only if i add any links in the place of url its opening...

Comment: give your gtalk id bcz u are not able to chat here with 1 reputation

Comment: See my updated post . To open pdf file in android use pdf link from your server, don't use local pdf link. Above code is tested and working fine .